# App Store App shows iAd "Test Advertisement"

Tags: iphone, iad

My app has been accepted by Apple and I just downloaded the version from the App Store. However the application still shows the test advertisement ad in the iAd banner. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you show how iAds is setup in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the app from your phone and computer, and then resyncing. Chances are you've got a development version on the phone that wasn't overwritten by your app store purchase.

Comment: I have attempted to do this, doesn't work... Wanna download the app to your phone and see if real ads show?

Comment: sure, i'm game. what's the app?

Comment: Link to app: bit.ly/fractioncalculatorpro
App Name: Fraction Calculator Pro
Promo Codes:

PHXFWKAP9W6A 
AK7XFWPAR4E7

Comment: wow someone else jumped on those promo codes even though you only posted them an hour ago. oh well, i hope they respond and let you know if the ads work or not.

Comment: on another note though (and i'm not at all trying to dictate anything to you), but AFAIK, it's bad practice to charge for an app plus have ads on it. I guess that's just my 2 cents

Answer (score 1):

Since when is the app available?

If it's for more than one day I would just login to itunes connect and check the iAd statistics.

Due to the unavailability of iAds in my country I could never see real iAds for my app but from the statistics I know they work.

Comment: It doesn't have that many users. Also it shows the Test Advertisement. It should either show a real ad or not populate with an ad and not show.